# Asking questions and winning prizes

Tags: discussion, site-activity

I recently saw [this post](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/contest-ask-questions-earn-badges-win-prizes?cb=1) on Writing Stack Exchange. It's essentially a contest where users who ask the highest number of upvoted questions with certain tags can receive Stack Exchange swag (generously provided by Stack Exchange itself). It's essentially an effort to boost activity on the site. What do you all think about this? Is it worth considering for our site?

Comment: It's a nice initiative, but, uhm..., Stack Exchange has not contacted us about swag they want to donate ... I think Writing SE got that because they were fulfilling the graduation criteria. We don't come close to fulfilling those criteria.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Oh, okay. I didn't know that.

Comment: We can still do competitions, with just kudos as a prize :)